# Convert DER formatted private key file to PEM form

Tags: openssl, private-key, pem, der

I have a .prv file which is probably DER formatted private key file.
This file is used to certificate Cable Modem.

I want to convert this file to PEM formatted one.
I tried with openssl tool but none of below commands works.

```
openssl x509 -inform der -in FILENAME.prv -out FILENAME.key
openssl rsa -inform der -in FILENAME.prv -out FILENAME.key
openssl pkcs8 -inform der -in FILENAME.prv -out FILENAME.key
```

Here is some beginning of the .prv file contents.

```
00000000h: 30 82 02 76 02 01 00 30 0D 06 09 2A 86 48 86 F7 ; 0?v...0...*낷놑
00000010h: 0D 01 01 01 05 00 04 82 02 60 30 82 02 5C 02 01 ; .......?`0?\..
00000020h: 00 02 81 81 00 BB 0F 6E DE 49 59 13 4A 44 12 AF ; ..걖.?n?Y.JD.?
00000030h: 84 F0 B7 13 18 C8 F8 43 AE 09 A6 8A 6C 9B F0 AC ; 꾭?.힉C?쫲l쏊?
00000040h: 90 1F 48 C2 75 75 41 78 74 FA DD 08 19 E0 C0 BF ; ?H혋uAxt玹..敾?
00000050h: CC 98 D7 72 B7 C3 8C 4A 2A B9 BC 95 B6 9A 54 17 ; ??련똉*뭡빒숿.
00000060h: 7C 5A 57 78 E1 68 87 69 18 56 8E 5D F4 D5 36 46 ; |ZWx?뇁.V?添6F
00000070h: DF 0F 6D 54 FC 30 B6 16 AD AF D2 C6 A8 D0 C1 F7 ; ?mT???盧ⓓ직
```

Is there anything more I can try??

Comment: This could be a private format which is not supported by OpenSSL. I suggest using an ASN.1 editor / viewer (for example http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4910/ASN-1-Editor) to look at the data.

Comment: DER format is not enough to know actual encoding of a private key. it might still be more than a private key, like pkcs12.... like @Omi suggested try openssl asn1parse -in FILENAME.prv...

Comment: openssl asn1parse -in k.bin -inform DER
    0:d=0  hl=4 l= 630 cons: SEQUENCE          
    4:d=1  hl=2 l=   1 prim: INTEGER           :00
    7:d=1  hl=2 l=  13 cons: SEQUENCE          
    9:d=2  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :rsaEncryption
   20:d=2  hl=2 l=   0 prim: NULL              
   22:d=1  hl=4 l= 608 prim: OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]

Comment: Thanks all. I solved this problem with ASN-1-Editor. I edited to remove unnecessary fields, then I could convert to PEM formatted one.